# Would the public key of Digital Signature be replaced?

Tags: signature

According to my understanding, Digital Signature is a technology to use private key/public key to sign/verify data in order to ensure data authentication, integrity and non-repudiation. Sender signs the data with private key and send the signature with the original data to receiver, and receiver verify the signature to confirm the sender is trustworthy.

But I wonder how the receiver confirm whether the public key on his hand hasn't been changed?

I mean if it is possible that the public key has been intercepted and replaced with a fraudulent public key while transferring to the receiver, and finally receive a fraudulent message with a signature signed by a fraudulent private key? If there is a safe way to send a public key to receiver, why don't just send the message in the same way?

I tried to google for the answer but no luck, if you think this question is too simple you can just throw me the url or something, I am willing to study by myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Improve your wording please! **Digital Signature does _NOT_ encrypt/decrypt message**; it signs and verifies it. Encryption renders a message unintelligible, and Digital Signature does not. While your wording is semi-approriate in an RSA context, that breaks down entirely for other forms of Digital Signature, like (EC)DSA. Google _Digital Certificate_ for clues about your question.

Comment: Digital signatures are not a complete system, they are one mechanism. They assume public keys are known by everyone. In practice, this is often achieved by some sort of [public key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure).

Comment: @tylo Why isn't that an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*extended and transformed comment into an answer*

Digital signatures are not a complete system, they are one mechanism. They assume public keys are known by everyone.

In practice, this is often achieved by some sort of [public key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). In software it's also possible the program has the verification key hard-coded.

> If there is a safe way to send a public key to receiver, why don't just send the message in the same way?

Well, that's pretty much what the chain of certificiates in a PKI do - but the sender might be a different person then.